# Does reinstalling package also reinstall dependencies?

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, dpkg, deb

If package `A` depends on package `B`, if I **reinstall** package `B`, what would happen to `A`? Will it be forever removed? Will it be removed, and then reinstalled? Will it simply be ignored by the package manager?

I am mostly interested in RPMs (so `rpm`, `dnf` and `yum` tools), but I also need to support `deb` packages.

`rpm --replacepkgs` and `yum reinstall` seem promising, but I am not sure.

My goal is to reinstall `B`, without at all affecting `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I **reinstall** package `B`, what would happen to `A`?

Nothing.

> Will it be forever removed? Will it be removed, and then reinstalled? Will it simply be ignored by the package manager?

No, No, and also no:

Since a reinstallation doesn't change anything (not even transitory) about the dependency graph, the package is unaffected. Of course it's not *ignored*, it's properly handled (by remaining unaffected).

> `yum reinstall`

Nowadays, `yum` is just a different way to call `dnf` (hint: `less $(which yum)` will show you exactly that; there's no "yum" on your system anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies are generally not touched unless necessary (for example you upgrade a package and the new version requires a newer version of the dependency).

PS: I think `dnf` is preferred to `yum` these days.